# Was bedeutet »der betreibende Verein«?

Tags: meaning

> Die Adresse des Frauenhauses hält der betreibende Verein „Cocon“ geheim

Was bedeutet »der betreibende Verein« auf Englisch ?

Ich habe das in den Google-Übersetzer eingegeben, und habe als Ergebnis

> the operating club

bekommen. Ist das so richtig?

Comment: A 'Verein' is a registered association. It's something typical for Germany https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eingetragener_Verein

Comment: @Iris: Nein, nicht typisch für Deutschland. Im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum werden organisierte Gruppen, die bestimmte Bedingungen erfüllen, »Vereine« genannt. Also nicht nur in Deutschland, sondern auch in Österreich, der Schweiz, in Liechtenstein, in Belgien und in Italien (Südtirol). International ist dafür der Begriff »Non Profit Organisation« üblich, und unter diesem Namen kennt man Vereine auch in UK und in den USA. Auch in Frankreich gibt es Vereine, die dort natürlich nicht »Verein« sondern »association« heißen. Siehe https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verein

Comment: Der »eingetragene Verein« ist nur eine Rechtsform, die es genau so (mit genau diesem Namen) tatsächlich nur in Deutschland gibt. Aber alles, was man in Deutschland in einem *eingetragenen Verein* machen kann, kann man z.B. in Österreich in einem *Verein* machen. (Ich weiß das, ich war in drei Vereinen Vorstandsmitglied.)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, interessant, hast Du mehr Informationen zur Vereinskultur Belgiens?

Comment: @Hubert Schönast, worauf ich hinaus wollte ist, dass ein Verein etwas anderes ist als ein Club. Kleintierzüchterverein vs. Schachclub (AG) in der Schule.

Comment: @CarstenS: Ja: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vereinigung_ohne_Gewinnerzielungsabsicht

Comment: @Iris: Ein Verein ist nichts weiter als ein Club, dessen Statuten und Namen der Gründungs- und Vorstandsmitglieder in einem behördlichen Register hinterlegt sind. Andersrum formuliert: Es gibt Clubs, die behördlich registriert sind und die man »Vereine« nennt. Diese Clubs haben gesetzliche Rechte und Pflichten. Es gibt aber auch Clubs, die bei keiner Behörde registriert sind. Das sind zwar Clubs, aber keine Vereine, und sie haben weder besondere Rechte noch irgendwelche gesetzlichen Pflichten. Ein behördlich registrierter Verein darf sich (zumindest in Ö) durchaus auch »Club« nennen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> der betreibende Verein

"Verein" can mean "association", "club", "society", "assembly", "organization", and in some contexts even "outfit" or "charity".

"betreibend" means "operating something". However, this "something" is not the "Verein" itself, but something else (either implied or mentioned).

Getting back to your original sentence,

> Die Adresse des Frauenhauses hält der betreibende Verein "Cocon" geheim.

you would normally get the implication that the "Cocon" association is the one operating said "Frauenhaus". A possible translation of the whole sentence could be

> The women's shelter's address is kept secret by its operating "Cocon" association.

or (in an active mood)

> The "Cocon" association, who is operating the women's shelter, keeps its address a secret.

Comment: A club is not a 'Verein'

Comment: @Iris: "Verein" can mean any of "society", "club", "association", "union", "assembly", "organization", "outfit", or possibly even "charity", depending on context. Yes, "club" has a connotation as in "sports club", but OP's understanding problem was not about "Verein" but about "betreibend", so I focused on that aspect. (But in hindsight, I guess I should have chosen a more fitting translation)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on context. It could very well be an entity filing a motion or something similar, or pursuing, conducting, controlling, running, operating etc. something. No way to tell without context.